# Facebook Graph API - not able to get from name for all the comments on a post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-comments

I am using Facebook Graph API version 8. I want to get all the comments from a selected post along with the user who commented. I am asking for following permissions while connecting the Facebook Business page with my platform:

`'public_profile', 'email', 'pages_read_user_content', 'pages_read_engagement'`

My issue is that from all the comments received few of them have detail of the user who commented and few doesn't. I am using long live user access token to fetch the comments from the selected post.

Can anyone please help me identify the thing what I am doing wrong? Wrong access token or missing permission? I have tried a lot of things but could not figure out the issue.

Comment: Is your app in dev or in live mode? Those few users you can get the info for, are they users of your app?

Comment: My app is in live mode. Yes for those who I receive from name are users of my app.